# Recursive formula for "{} - {}".format(x, x+1) (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, return, string.format

Say y = 10

and x = 0

For x in range(y) function would print out numbers from 0 to 9.

teststring = "{} - {}".format(x, x+1)

How can I print string recursively as for the output to be:

0 - 1

1 - 2

2 - 3 and so on?

I have tried to do:

```
def inrangetest():
    x = 0
    y = 10
    for x in range(y):
        teststring = "{} - {}\n".format(x, x+1)

    return teststring

print(inrangetest()) #prints only 0 - 1 and nothing else
```

Though if I change the inrangetest() function into

```
def inrangetest():
    x = 0
    y = 10
    for x in range(y):
        teststring = "{} - {}\n".format(x, x+1)
    print(teststring)
```

It works but it prints out the numbers automatically without me
wanting it. What can I do for the function not to print the numbers but return them only when actually called by a print function?

Comment: None of your functions calls itself, I don't see any recursion here.

Comment: Well of course return ends the function and the for loop only gets to run 1 time. You can append teststring to a list created in your function and return that after for loop ends

Comment: I guess I might have expressed it the wrong way when I said recursion, or a recursive formula, it should call from a list of scores and actually show the players with the most major score, and each time a person plays the game it adds to the list. Though I guess maybe that's not really recursion. Either way, Aaron_ab's solution got the issue solved, and I understood the point ROAR made. Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, please notice that **'x=0'** in the **'inrangetest'** method does nothing. ***range(y)*** will generate all nums starting from **'0'**, so even if you start the method with: **'x=23'** it will still generate all nums from **0**..

You can fix this by writing something like:

```
for i in range(x,y):
  # do what ever..
```

Any way, the solution you are looking for is using 'yield'. 
Something like:

```
def generate_str(_from, _to):
   for i in range(_from, _to):
      yield '{}-{}'.format(i, i+1)


gen = generate_str(10, 30)
print(next(gen)) # 10-11
print(next(gen)) # 11-12
```

This way you control when you want to receive the next generates string and what to do with it..

notice that calling the generator by:

```
next(gen)
```

will eventually raise an **StopIteration**, so you can do something like:

```
with contextlib.suppress(StopIteration):
    print(next(gen)) # or what ever you need..
```

Comment: That actually did the trick! Thank you very much! I'm still new to python and unfortunately this is the first time I am presented to this "yield" utility. Either way, thank you very much!